# How to apply Canny Edge detector with cv::cuda and C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to apply Canny edge detector using cuda in opencv 4 and C++. My code is below

using namespace std;

int main() {

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("/path/to/image/test.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::cuda::GpuMat grayImage_gpu;
cv::cuda::GpuMat image_gpu(image);
cv::cuda::resize(image, image, cv::Size(), 0.3, 0.3);
cv::namedWindow("Image", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv::cuda::cvtColor(image_gpu, grayImage_gpu, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::Filter> gaussianFilter = cv::cuda::createGaussianFilter(grayImage_gpu.type(),
                                                                          grayImage_gpu.type(),
                                                                          cv::Size(7, 7),
                                                                          0);
gaussianFilter->apply(grayImage_gpu, grayImage_gpu);

cv::cuda::GpuMat edgedImage_gpu;
cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::CannyEdgeDetector> cannyFilter = cv::cuda::createCannyEdgeDetector(50, 100);
cannyFilter->detect(grayImage_gpu, edgedImage_gpu);
cv::Mat edgedImage(edgedImage_gpu);

cv::imwrite("cuda_canny.png", edgedImage);

//cv::namedWindow("Image", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
//cv::imshow("Image", edgedImage);
cv::waitKey(0);

return 0;
```

}

But when I run the code, I have the next error:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.2.0-pre) /home/user/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp:359: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) getGpuMat is available only for cuda::GpuMat and cuda::HostMem in function 'getGpuMat'`

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [upload and download](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html) functions to convert data between mat and gpumat.